# Adding text to the center of pie chart: Highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

How do I add total value to the center of pie chart. I have tried the following. It should basically show the total value of y values.

Input

```
export const data = [
  {
    y: 15,
    name: "Category 1"
  },
  {
    y: 25,
    name: "Category 2"
  },
  {
    y: 35,
    name: "Category 3"
  },

];
```

Here it should show 75 at the centre of the pie chart. (i.e total count of y values)
Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-line-chart-forked-edqfb?file=/src/LineChart.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import HC_exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
HC_exporting(Highcharts);

function Chart(props) {
  const chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: "pie",
      height: 250
    },
    title: {
      verticalAlign: "middle",
      floating: true,
      text: "test"
    },
    legend: {
      layout: "vertical",
      align: "right",
      verticalAlign: "top",
      itemMarginTop: 5,
      itemMarginBottom: 5
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: "pointer",
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        showInLegend: true
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: props.chartData,
        size: "80%",
        innerSize: "50%,",
        text: "Test"
      }
    ]
  };
  return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions} />;
}

export default Chart;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class and add a text element in a calculated position. Example:

```
    chart: {
        ...,
        events: {
            render: function() {
                var series = this.series[0],
                    seriesCenter = series.center,
                    x = seriesCenter[0] + this.plotLeft,
                    y = seriesCenter[1] + this.plotTop,
                    text = 'Total: ' + series.total,
                    fontMetrics = this.renderer.fontMetrics(16);

                if (!this.customTitle) {
                    this.customTitle = this.renderer.text(
                            text,
                            null,
                            null,
                            true
                        )
                        .css({
                            transform: 'translate(-50%)',
                            fontSize: '16px',
                            color: 'red'
                        })
                        .add();
                }

                this.customTitle.attr({
                    x,
                    y: y + fontMetrics.f / 2
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mrg2qt6c/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

Comment: Can we pass a css class to this SVGRenderer. As I need to toggle between colors for light and dark mode?

Comment: Yes, you can use `addClass` method. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bxzqojs6/

Comment: Hi @li97, Could you explain the problem in more details?

Comment: with the help of your code, I was able to get the text to the center. Now I want to dynamically change this text based on the some filter value. Say,  I have  different filters that returns me different set of data points, in my case the text remains constant. It doesnt get reloaded on filter change. Any redraw or update can be used?

Comment: basically chatr re-renders but the center text does not

Comment: Thanks for the info! Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/srjowdfc/ you can find an updated example.